# In Objective-C, can I declare @property on a c-array of floats?

Tags: objective-c

thing.h

```
@interface Thing : NSObject 
{
     float stuff[30];
}

@property float stuff;
@end
```

thing.m

```
@implementation Thing
@synthesize stuff;
@end
```

I get **error: type of property 'stuff' does not match type of ivar 'stuff'**

I don't want to use an NSArray because I'd have to make the floats into NSNumbers (right?) and that's a pain to do math with.

**Update**:  I've noticed similar answers had guesses and trial answers. While I appreciate the attempts by non-Objective-C folks, I'm hoping for a **definitive** answer whether it's possible or not.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to insert them as NSNumbers as NSArray only accepts object values; however, you can access the float value by simply calling [number floatValue] where number is your NSNumber object.

Comment: That seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I have compiled up the following code at it works as expected.

**FloatHolder.h**

```
@interface FloatHolder : NSObject {
    int _count;
    float* _values;
}

- (id) initWithCount:(int)count;

// possibly look into this for making access shorter
// http://vgable.com/blog/2009/05/15/concise-nsdictionary-and-nsarray-lookup/
- (float)getValueAtIndex:(int)index;
- (void)setValue:(float)value atIndex:(int)index;

@property(readonly) int count;
@property(readonly) float* values; // allows direct unsafe access to the values

@end
```

**FloatHolder.m**

```
#import "FloatHolder.h"


@implementation FloatHolder

@synthesize count = _count;
@synthesize values = _values;

- (id) initWithCount:(int)count {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _count = count;
        _values = malloc(sizeof(float)*count);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    free(_values);

    [super dealloc];
}

- (float)getValueAtIndex:(int)index {
    if(index<0 || index>=_count) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName: @"Exception" reason: @"Index out of bounds" userInfo: nil];
    }

    return _values[index];
}

- (void)setValue:(float)value atIndex:(int)index {
    if(index<0 || index>=_count) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName: @"Exception" reason: @"Index out of bounds" userInfo: nil];
    }

    _values[index] = value;
}

@end
```

then in your other application code you can do something like the following:

** FloatTestCode.h **

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "FloatHolder.h"

@interface FloatTestCode : NSObject {
    FloatHolder* holder;
}

- (void) doIt:(id)sender;

@end
```

** FloatTestCode.m **

```
#import "FloatTestCode.h"


@implementation FloatTestCode

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        holder = [[[FloatHolder alloc] initWithCount: 10] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [holder release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) doIt:(id)sender {
    holder.values[1] = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The type of the property must match the type of the instance variable it will be stored in, so you could do something like

```
  @interface Thing : NSObject 
  {
       float stuff[30];
  }

  @property float[30] stuff;
  @end
```

and it should work.  I wouldn't recommend it though.
I'm guessing you're looking for something like indexed properties from Delphi.  The closest you'll get is something like the following.

```
  @interface Thing : NSObject 
  {
       float stuff[30];
  }

  - (void) setStuff:(float)value atIndex:(int)index;
  - (float) getStuffAtIndex:(int)index;
  @end
```

Comment: You could simply make the property readonly and then read and set values at specific indices with the normal array operator. But I like yours better because it's more encapsulated.

Comment: That failed to compile with a syntax error. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it the way you want to do it.  You can jump through some hoops and get something similar, e.g. using [Daniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897639/in-objective-c-can-i-declare-property-on-a-c-array-of-floats/900855#900855), but it's not quite the same thing.  The reason you can't do it is that **arrays are not lvalues in C**.  An lvalue is something that can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment.  The following code is invalid C:

```
float stuff1[30], stuff2[30];
stuff1 = stuff2;  // ERROR: arrays are not lvalues
```

As a consequence, you can't declare properties whose types are not lvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's FloatHolder answer has a major bug (edit: he's now fixed it). It only allocates memory for one float and not for the whole array.

The line:

> `_values = malloc(sizeof(float));`

Should be:

> `_values = malloc(sizeof(float) * count);`

Otherwise it seems to be a good answer. Sorry couldn't work out how to reply directly. (edit: I didn't have the necessary privilege on stackoverflow then.)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get that to compile, it wouldn't behave well. 'stuff' would return a float*, and the client would have no idea how long the array way; 'setStuff:' would just change the pointer, and you'd either be pointing to stack-allocated data that would vanish out from under you or heap-allocated data that would leak because it wouldn't know to free it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well-versed in Objective-C 2.0, but I'm guessing that the issue might be caused by the fact that a C array is essentially just a *pointer* to the first element of the array, meaning that the type of `float stuff[30]` is actually `float *`, not merely a `float`.

Comment: No, C arrays are not pointers, they are arrays.  It just so happens that arrays implicitly decay into pointers to their first elements, but there is still a difference between arrays and pointers.